# how to append my values to google spreadsheets OAUTH/GAPI js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I want to create chrome extension which appends text in google sheets using oauth and google apis(gapi);
can u show me code example? i have this code in background.js

```
function onGAPILoad() {
  gapi.client.init({
 
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('gapi initialized')
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
      gapi.auth.setToken({
        'access_token': token,
      });
      gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range: 'Sheet1',
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      

      });
    })
    

  }, function(error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  })
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have now?

Comment: i want to add append code